# Check inputs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

In my situation I have problem, I trying to check inputs if they empty it should put "has-error" style, but it does not checking.. What I missing ?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#submit").click(function() {
    var username = jQuery("#username").val();
    var password = jQuery("#password").val();
    jQuery('#username, #password').removeClass("has_error");
    if (username === '') {
      jQuery('#username').parent().find('input').addClass("has_error");
    } else {
      jQuery('#username').parent().find('input').removeClass("has_error");
    }
    
    if (password === '') {
      jQuery('#password').parent().find('input').addClass("has_error");
    } else {
      jQuery('#password').parent().find('input').removeClass("has_error");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="navigation.html" method="post" id="query-form" class="form-signin">
  <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="submit">
    Prisijungti
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you doing anything to prevent the form from being submitted? Also, when you do `.parent().find('input')` you're selecting all the inputs, not just the one that is empty.

Comment: Agreed. I suggest `jQuery('#query-form').on('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault(); ... }`

Answer (score 2):

This looks correct, but you are trying to apply the class to a parent input, which from the code given doesn't exist. It looks like you should remove all instances of: `.parent().find('input')`

Also, as noted by [showdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924299/showdev) if the condition of "being empty" is met, then you need to `return false` on the form (don't submit)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#submit").click(function() {
    var username = jQuery("#username").val();
    var password = jQuery("#password").val();
    jQuery('#username, #password').removeClass("has_error");
    if (username === '') {
      jQuery('#username').addClass("has_error");
      return false;
    } else {
      jQuery('#username').removeClass("has_error");
    }
    if (password === '') {
      jQuery('#password').addClass("has_error");
      return false;
    } else {
      jQuery('#password').removeClass("has_error");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="navigation.html" method="post" id="query-form" class="form-signin">
  <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username"     placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="submit">
    Prisijungti
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: And also prevent the form from being submitted unless the fields are both filled.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = jQuery("#username").val();
    var password = jQuery("#password").val();

    //rest of code

    $('#query-form').submit(); // once checks complete
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be simplified since you're just checking empty. Note: you could add the `required` attribute instead. But anyway, check this out.

## edit

## [Demo](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/68c7922ef716e1f00085c3e4c331dbe7?editors=101)

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var $inputs = $(this).siblings('input'),
            isValid = true;
        $inputs.each(function() { 
          var hasError = !$(this)[0].value.length;
          isValid = isValid && !hasError;
          $(this).toggleClass('has_error', hasError);
        });
      
        return isValid;
    });
});
```